# JSch - How to issue commands as the user I have switched to

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, su

I am using Jsch to remotely connect to a Linux server from Windows 7.

I have to

```
(i) login to Linux server with my credentials 
(ii) switch to root using a pmrun command [this is the procedure in our environment], and
(iii) execute su command to switch as "someuser"
(iv) execute further commands as that "someuser"
```

I completed the steps (i) and (ii).

After completing step (ii), the InputStream from the channel shows the command-prompt as that of the root user.  So I assume that I have become the root user now.

Now, do I need to get the root user's session to further execute an su command, or is there a way to execute further commands as the root user?

Someone please help. Thanks.

**Update:** Source code

```
public class Pmrun {

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        try{
            JSch jsch=new JSch();

            String host=null;
            if(arg.length>0){
                host=arg[0];
            }
            else{
                host="myself@linuxserver.com";
            }
            String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
            host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

            Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

            UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
            session.setUserInfo(ui);
            session.connect();

            String command=  "pmrun su -";

            Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");

            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outStream = channel.getOutputStream();
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true);
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            channel.connect();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
            outStream.write("xxxxxxx\n".getBytes());
            outStream.flush();

            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("su - someuser");


            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
            while(true){
                while(in.available()>0){
                    int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if(i<0)break;
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if(channel.isClosed()){
                    System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo{
        public String getPassword(){ return passwd; }
        public boolean promptYesNo(String str){
            str = "Yes";
            return true;}

        String passwd;

        public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
        public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return true; }
        public boolean promptPassword(String message){
            passwd="zzzzzzzz";
            return true;
        }
        public void showMessage(String message){

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Can't you try sending some `whoami` or `id`, to figure out? After the `su` you are root so send the commands, the inputStream is just some channel

Comment: Of course, i tried. But i got no result.  The channel I used to execute "whoami" belongs to my session and not that of the root.  Is there a way that can i see the result?

Comment: Show us the code!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Updated the question with the code. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to execute `su - someuser` within `pmrun su -`?

Comment: Once i do a pmrun, i become root. Now i have to switch to "someuser" and issue commands. This is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending @Martin's answer, the other solution would be to open the channel in "shell" mode which would maintain the session. Like this...

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell")
```

Comment: The "shell" channel is not a good solution for automating command execution. It's intended for implementing an interactive session (e.g. PuTTY uses the "shell" channel). Though in edge cases, it is a viable "hack".

Comment: Thanks Shubham. This suggestion is feasible for me now.

Answer (score 1):

With the "exec" channel, you can execute a single command only.

The other command is executed within the `su`, not after the `su` anyway.

- one solution is to provide the other command on a `su` command-line, like:

  ```
  su -c command
  ```
- or feed the command to the `su` using its standard input:

  ```
  outStream.write(("command\n").getBytes());
  ```

In general, I recommend the first approach as it uses a better defined API (command-line argument).

Comment: Thanks for that information.  My case is that, I have to issue further commands only as 'someuser' i.e. after "su - someuser".  So is there any other answer to my situation?

Comment: Manual steps: I login as "MyUser". Then do a "pmrun su -" and enter the required password. Now the prompt shows "[root@linuxserver~]#". Then I have to do "su - someuser". The prompt now shows "/home/someuser>". I need to run shell scripts from here, say "./run.sh".  Can you please share some snippets of how I can achieve the above, using the method you suggested?

Comment: If the `su` requires password, you need to provide it via input stream. Though note that automating password input is a bad solution. A password is to be entered by a human. If you want to automate executing a command that requires `su`, allow the `su` to proceed without password (for that specific command only).

Comment: To execute the two `su`'s, use a command like `pmrun su - -c "su - someuser -c \"command 1; command2 ; command 3\""`

Comment: Ok, i need to approach the Linux admin then, to enable me to use the commands that way. At least for the time being i will not be able to proceed the recommended way. Thank you for your time and the recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but after lot of R&D and scanning through SO links was finally able to resolve it. Here is the program that worked for me.

```
public class SSHConn {

    static Session session;
    static String suCmds = "su - simba -c \"whoami ; pwd\"";
    static String[] commands = {"whoami", suCmds};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        open();
        runCmd(commands);
        close();
    }

    public static void runCmd(String[] commands) throws JSchException, IOException {
        for (String cmd : commands) {
            System.out.println("\nExecuting command: " + cmd);
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(cmd);
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
            channel.connect();
            //passing creds only when you switch user
            if (cmd.startsWith("su -")) {
                System.out.println("Setting suPasswd now....");
                out.write((Constants.suPasswd + "\n").getBytes());
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Flushed suPasswd to cli...");
            }
            captureCmdOutput(in, channel);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            channel.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public static void captureCmdOutput(InputStream in, Channel channel) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Capturing cmdOutput now...");
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                System.out.println(ee.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void open() throws JSchException {
        JSch jSch = new JSch();
        session = jSch.getSession(Constants.userId, Constants.host, 22);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.setPassword(Constants.userPasswd);
        System.out.println("Connecting SSH to " + Constants.host + " - Please wait for few seconds... ");
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected!\n");
    }

    public static void close() {
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("\nDisconnected channel and session");
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Connecting SSH to my-unix-box.net - Please wait for few seconds... 
Connected!

Executing command: whoami
Capturing cmdOutput now...
john

Executing command: su - simba -c "whoami ; pwd"
Setting suPasswd now....
Flushed suPasswd to cli...
Capturing cmdOutput now...
simba
/home/simba

Disconnected channel and session
```

Answer (score 0):

The way pmrun works is it matches your User ID and/or primary local group ID (or netgroup) to a role-based profile that has been setup. This profile will give you rights to execute commands they have authorised within the profile. Without running the pmrun command it wont match you to one of their profiles and therefore the command will be rejected. if you have a look in your /opt/quest/bin folder you will see other prewrapped shells that you can use. Running the pmwrapped_bash is the same as running pmrun bash. From their you can then issue the command sudo -s to get Sudo root access and/or su - someuser to enter access that accounts privileges.

Did you end up getting the code you need or is this issue still a problem for you that I could assist.

For me, I need to pass through the users variables as we execute the pmrun $shell from within the /etc/profile file so that users dont need to type this and therefore their scripts works the same.

Regards Nomadz

Comment: I managed with the accepted answer. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I am using the given below command in order to copy the files , static String suCmds = "pbrun su - myjobs -c \"cd /apps/myapp/loader/error ;cp /apps/myapp/loader/error/one.txt /users/myuserid/one.txt;\" ";  file is not copied to user directory and there is no error  ? Can you have suggestion on this ?

Comment: @Nital  is there any way to execute cd command / and cp command using JSCH java ? after PBRUN SU command ?